# Fooling with variables and querys

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm doing my best to compartmentalize all of my code so the it's completely flexible. However I'm running into an issue when I try to run the code. It goes like this On Click you've entered is producing: invalid outside procedure.

At the top of my program I have a few variables that look like this:

```
Public Sub varHolder() 'this
    Dim monday As String
Dim tuesday As String
Dim wednesday As String
Dim thursday As String
Dim friday As String
Dim day As String
Dim stepQuery As String
Dim i As Integer

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsStepCalendar As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsStepCalendar = stepQuery
end sub
```

The next part of my program I start to fill those variables with values.

```
Private Sub btnNewContact_Click()

call varHolder 'this
Dim header As Integer

header = Forms!frmContactsEdit!txtHeader.Value

If chkActive = True Then
    stepQuery = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblStepCalendar " & _
                                            "Where (HeaderID = '" & header & "' ) " & _
                                            "AND (Cancel = False)" & _
                                            "AND (Active = True)", dbOpenDynaset)
    monday = chkMonA.Value
    tuesday = chkTuesA.Value
    wednesday = chkWedA.Value
    thursday = chkThursA.Value
    friday = chkFriA.Value
    day = lstActive.Selected(i)

    Call stepUpdater

End If

If chkRetiree = True Then
    stepQuery = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblStepCalendar " & _
                                            "Where (HeaderID = '" & header & "' ) " & _
                                            "AND (Cancel = False)" & _
                                            "AND (Retiree = True)", dbOpenDynaset)
    monday = chkMonB.Value
    tuesday = chkTuesB.Value
    wednesday = chkWedB.Value
    thursday = chkThursB.Value
    friday = chkFriB.Value
    day = lstRetiree.Selected(i)

    Call stepUpdater

End If

If chkCobra = True Then
    stepQuery = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblStepCalendar " & _
                                            "Where (HeaderID = '" & header & "' ) " & _
                                            "AND (Cancel = False)" & _
                                            "AND (Cobra = True)", dbOpenDynaset)
    monday = chkMonC.Value
    tuesday = chkTuesC.Value
    wednesday = chkWedC.Value
    thursday = chkThursC.Value
    friday = chkFriC.Value
    day = lstCobra.Selected(i)

    Call stepUpdater

End If
End Sub
```

After I execute the code with the proper variables.

```
Public Sub stepUpdater()

call varHolder 'this
If rsStepCalendar.EOF Then

    RstRecSet.Add
    rsStepCalendar("Monday").Value = monday
    rsStepCalendar("Tuesday").Value = tuesday
    rsStepCalendar("Wednesday").Value = wednesday
    rsStepCalendar("Thursday").Value = thursday
    rsStepCalendar("Friday").Value = friday
    RstRecSet.Update

    For i = 0 To 32
        If day <> rsStepCalendar(i).Value Then
        RstRecSet.Add
            rsStepCalendar(i).Value = rsStepCalendar(i).Value
        RstRecSet.Update
        End If
   Next

    MsgBox ("Record Added")

Else
    If chkMonA <> rsStepCalendar("Monday").Value Then
        RstRecSet.Edit
                rsStepCalendar("Monday").Value = monday
        RstRecSet.Update
    End If

    If chkTuesA <> rsStepCalendar("Tuesday").Value Then
        RstRecSet.Edit
                rsStepCalendar("Tuesday").Value = tuesday
        RstRecSet.Update
    End If

    If chkWedA <> rsStepCalendar("Wednesday").Value Then
        RstRecSet.Edit
                rsStepCalendar("Wednesday").Value = wednesday
        RstRecSet.Update
    End If

    If chkThursA <> rsStepCalendar("Thursday").Value Then
        RstRecSet.Edit
                rsStepCalendar("Thursday").Value = thursday
        RstRecSet.Update
    End If

    If chkFriA <> rsStepCalendar("Friday").Value Then
        RstRecSet.Edit
                rsStepCalendar("Friday").Value = friday
        RstRecSet.Update
    End If

For i = 0 To 32

        If day <> rsStepCalendar(i).Value Then
            RstRecSet.Edit
                rsStepCalendar(i).Value = rsStepCalendar(i).Value
            RstRecSet.Update
        End If
Next
End If

End Sub
```

My question is am I doing something I'm not suppose to? Does the error stem from me trying to use all these functions? The problem with the error I'm getting is I can debug so I'm clueless as to what I'm doing wrong.

**Edits**:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsStepCalendar As DAO.Recordset
Call Initialize

Sub Initialize()
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsStepCalendar = stepQuery
End Sub
```

Comment: `Does the error stem` - **What error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> at the top of my program I have a few variables that look like this:

This being the case, your error is due to an assignment of *variables* outside of a `Sub` or `Function` block.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsStepCalendar As DAO.Recordset
' Can't do assignments outside of a Sub or Function.
--> Set db = CurrentDb
--> Set rsStepCalendar = stepQuery
```

Only `Const` values can be assigned in the global scope declaration area.

To fix your error, move the `Set` lines into a `Sub` or `Function` code block:

```
Dim monday As String
Dim tuesday As String
Dim wednesday As String
Dim thursday As String
Dim friday As String
Dim day As String
Dim stepQuery As String
Dim i As Integer

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsStepCalendar As DAO.Recordset

' Call this sub once to set the variable values.
Sub Initialize()
    Set db = CurrentDb
    ' This wouldn't work because stepQuery is a string.
    ' Only included here to show assignment should be outside global declaration area.
    Set rsStepCalendar = stepQuery
end sub
```

Comment: So would I put them in a function and call the function where ever i need it?

Comment: @SaladSnake - The function which sets the values would only need to be called once since their scope is global. Once set, they will be available everywhere.

Comment: I'm a bit confused to i'll update the code up top. Let me know if i've got the right idea.

Comment: @SaladSnake - If these values will never change once set, it would be a good idea to have a `Sub Initialize` which sets them appropriately. Then you simply call this sub at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Alright so I added updates. I put a "this" next to everything i've added. Is that what you were trying to explain to me? The variables will change a lot.

Comment: @SaladSnake - Regarding your edit - No. If you wrap all the variable declarations a Sub, then the scope will not be global - it will only be for the sub itself. Your original code was fine, you just needed to move the `Set` statements. See my previous comment.

Comment: This is what I tried but i still get the same on click error(code uptop). I believe I followed your suggestion correctly.

Comment: I see. I think it worked however i have some other errors i need to work out before i can fully be sure. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: @SaladSnake - No problem - glad to help. Good luck with your project.